Remix Web client loads, and then becomes blank. Can't see any UI, can't click on anything
After pasting a script into the web client, I compiled and the page went blank. Waited for a couple minutes, tried refreshing the page, pasting scripts into the console, etc. Still a blank page. Everything shows for a split second upon opening the page, but it becomes blank afterwards.

Which browser were you using? What site did you use? The official site https://remix.ethereum.org/ is working fine with Chrome, Brave, Firefox on Mac and Linux.
